# How to add different or new class to element based on variable options

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to add different classes to a div on the basis of different values of variable.

For example

I have a variable

```
Var layoutColumn = 1;
```

I want this variable to take  1 to 4 options by user.

If user select say 1 then on the basis of this selection, I want to add new class to div i.e.

```
<div class = "layout layoutCol1"></div>
```

Similarly, if the user select option 2 then div shoud have new class such as

```
<div class = "layout layoutCol2"></div>
```

and so on...

Thanks

Comment: Don't capitalize `var`  and just to form a better habit, use `let` or `const` instead. Also, you should post the JavaScript that you tried and failed with so we can fix it. See [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems [no attempt was made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Please, [help us reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting helpful answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add id to that element and get it with getElementById

```
let element = document.getElementById('yourId')
switch(layoutColumn) {
     case 1:
       element.className = 'layoutCol1';
       break
    case 2:
       element.className = 'layoutCol2';
       break

}
```

and so all...